# Jquery Cycle Plugin + Videos

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I working on a jcycle bug in Chrome. I have a jcycle rotator setup to rotate youtube videos for a portfolio. The problem is when the page is loaded or refreshed in Chrome, one of the videos that should be hidden shows up in the left top corner. When I implement the display none fix from the FAQ's, it hides all videos but the first permenantly. See examples below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

WITHOUT Display none Fix: (Videos pop up at left:0 top:0)
http://www.tweedstudios.com/!/broadcast.php

WITH Display none Fix: (Videos are permanently hidden)
http://www.tweedstudios.com/!/broadcast2.php

Also, there's another bug in Safari. I'm sure it's CSS related but I can't pin point it. Thanks again!

Comment: What version of chrome? I couldn't reproduce the error 'WITHOUT Display none fix' and it seemed to work fine. I'm on Chrome 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The youtube iFrame's in your second example are set to displayLnone.  I'd suggest you use the visibility:hidden instead and then in the jquery cycle before event on the jquery cycle plugin you can change it to visible before the slide transitions.

[The Youtube video in my hidden DIV only starts to load after the DIV is shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156794/the-youtube-video-in-my-hidden-div-only-starts-to-load-after-the-div-is-shown)

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html

Comment: The chrome issue has been fixed with position:absolute; top:0; left:0; on the slides and iframes.  Although, I am still having issues in SAFARI.  It's as if overflow hidden isn't working.  http://www.tweedstudios.com/!/broadcast3.php

Comment: I checked it on safari mac and there is no issue although when I click play the slideshow never stops to let me see the video.

Comment: @TravisHedrick Append `&wmode=opaque` to the url of each video.  It should fix the safari issue.

Comment: @TravisHedrick Did this answer help you fix the issue?  If so, I'd appreciate you marking the answer (click the checkmark). If not, can you provide some feedback?